# Search in toolbar

Tags: java, android, search, toolbar

Want make search in toolbar, but dont know why gradle show me error.
Someone have ideas how fix it?

**FragmentFolder.java:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:showAsAction="always||collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

    />
</menu>
```

**Messages Gradle Build:**

> C:\MyWork\VideoPlayer\app\src\main\res\menu\main.xml Error:(10, 27)
>   String types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value
>   'always||collapseActionView').

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `app:showAsAction="always||collapseActionView"` with 
`app:showAsAction=["always | collapseActionView"]`

Comment: Attribute value expected